# How to implement Interstitial iAds in Swift(Xcode 6.1)

Tags: swift, ios8, iad, xcode6.1, interstitial

I am trying to figure out how to switch over from my banner view iAds to interstitial iAds in order to free up space for a tabbed controller. For some reason I am completely unable to find any resource for even getting started on these ads with swift.

Could anyone please give me some information on interstitial iAds with Swift and how I can implement them in a project.

Comment: Check out [Swift AdMob Tutorial](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/) - Literally just been through this whole ordeal myself until I found this. (iAds is closing down.)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a relatively cleaner and easier to follow way to implement Interstitial Ads since this way doesn't require the use of `NSNotificationCentre`

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadInterstitialAd()
}

func loadInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interstitialAd.delegate = self
}

func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView = UIView()
    interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

    interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
}

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

And it may help if you put `println("Function Name")` in each function just to keep track of your Interstitial Ads process. If you have any questions and or a way to improve this block of code please leave a comment. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Here is how i use in my project

//adding  iAd framework

```
 import iAd
```

//conform iAd delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ADInterstitialAdDelegate 


//create instance variable
var interstitial:ADInterstitialAd!
```

//default iAd interstitials does not provide close button so we need to create one manually

```
var placeHolderView:UIView!
var closeButton:UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //iAD interstitial
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("runAd:"),    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}




//iAD interstitial
func runAd(notification:NSNotification){
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
cycleInterstitial()
}

func cycleInterstitial(){

    // Clean up the old interstitial...
    //  interstitial.delegate = nil;
    // and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when
    interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
    interstitial.delegate = self;
}

func presentInterlude(){
    // If the interstitial managed to load, then we'll present it now.
    if (interstitial.loaded) {

        placeHolderView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(placeHolderView)

        closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y:  25, width: 25, height: 25))
        closeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "error"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("close"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(closeButton)


        interstitial.presentInView(placeHolderView)
    }
}

// iAd Delegate Mehtods

// When this method is invoked, the application should remove the view from the screen and tear it down.
// The content will be unloaded shortly after this method is called and no new content will be loaded in that view.
// This may occur either when the user dismisses the interstitial view via the dismiss button or
// if the content in the view has expired.

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

    cycleInterstitial()
}


func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(_interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

    println("called just before dismissing - action finished")

}

// This method will be invoked when an error has occurred attempting to get advertisement content.
// The ADError enum lists the possible error codes.
func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!,
    didFailWithError error: NSError!){
        cycleInterstitial()
}


//Load iAd interstitial
func dislayiAdInterstitial() {
    //iAd interstitial
    presentInterlude()
}


func close() {
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

}
```

Comment: Great code! I got this working, but I'm curious why there is 3.0 in the line: NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Comment: So basically Ads use data. So you need to wait 3 seconds to give the ad a chance to be downloaded in order to be used even if service isn't good.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old - but I just came across

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
               sender: AnyObject?) {

let destination = segue.destinationViewController 
            as UIViewController
destination.interstitialPresentationPolicy = 
    ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to your app delegate, you'll avoid that 3 second delay suggested above.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
        return true
    }
```